# Reactivity while using ggvis/shiny

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

I am new to Shiny/ggvis and I want to create a scatter plot that allows the user to select from an X and Y dropdown. I have attempted this feat may times to no avail and would greatly appreciate some help. Please see the code below.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)
library(dplyr)

# Define the user interface

  shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
    # Add a title to this page

    headerPanel(
      h1("Test the Header Panel!")),


    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("ggvis_ui"),
      sliderInput(inputId = "size",label = "Area",10, 1000, value = c(10)),
      selectInput(inputId = "yAxis",label = "Y variable", c("wt","drat")),      
      selectInput(inputId = "xAxis",label = " X variable", c("cyl", "am","gear"))),



    mainPanel(
      h1("Please review the chart below showing nothing!"),

      ggvisOutput("ggvis")

      )


  )

  )
```

Server.r

```
# Create server.R

    shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

      # A reactive expression wrapper for input$size
      input_size <- reactive(input$size)
      input_xAxis <- reactive(input$xAxis)
      input_yAxis <- reactive(input$yAxis)

      # A reactive expression wrapper for input$size


      mtcars %>% 
        ggvis(x =input_xAxis, y = input_yAxis, size := input_size) %>%
        layer_points() %>%
        bind_shiny("ggvis", "ggvis_ui")


    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two things you are missing is making the plot reactive and using `prop` for setting properties when the variables names are strings.

The following change to the server code returns a reactive graphic:

```
plot = reactive({
    mtcars %>%
    ggvis(prop("x", as.name(input_xAxis())), 
         prop("y", as.name(input_yAxis())), 
         size := input_size) %>%
    layer_points()
    })

plot %>%
    bind_shiny("ggvis", "ggvis_ui")
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I'm fairly new to shiny and your response has helped me a great deal. Thank you!

Comment: @Get_it_Going Glad to help!  If this solved the issue, you can click the check mark next to the answer.